# How can i implement roles/permission based crud routing on react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using react-redux. I can create as many roles as i need, and a single user can be assigned multiple roles. roles contains the array of resources, each resource contains {canView,canAdd,canUpdate, canDelete}
for eg: admin role contains

```
{id, name, resourceRole: [{canAdd:true, canView:true, canUpdate:true, canDelete: true, resourceId:1 },{canAdd:true, canView:true, canUpdate:true, canDelete: true, resourceId:2}])
```

and so on. Now I am stuck at how to create routing for roles. Is there any way i can acomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply not render the route if the current user's permissions aren't sufficient?

```
const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.currentUser);
return (
    <div>
    {currentUser.resourceRole.find(r => r.resourceId === 1).canView && 
         <Route exact path="/resource/1" ... />}
    </div>
);
```

There are other ways if you want to build something dynamic/generic, but conditional logic like that is the simple approach.

Comment: But this way it will be long as I have more than 50 resources

Comment: You can loop over your list of resources and make this logic dynamic. Just need to map resource ids to route paths, and the corresponding component.